# Woocommerce WC_Cart->fees and WC_Cart::get_checkout_url are deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

I was wondering what happened to my Woocommerce or something after I updated the plugin. Some deprecation error occurs. Kindly see attached image below. How can I solved this thing? [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You need to replace **`WC_Cart::get_checkout_url`** it with [**`wc_get_checkout_url()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_checkout_url.html#1157-1174) instead, without using `WC()->cart` (or `WC_Cart::`)  as it's not a WC_Cart method anymore.

2) For **`WC_Cart->fees`**, you can replace it with [**`WC_Cart->get_fees()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_get_fees) or `WC()->cart->get_fees();`

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I tried using this as a solution, define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); How is it?

Comment: Well, yes. Thanks. But one more thing, I need to locate those classes that uses these functions. Where can I locate these?

Comment: That is the problem because WordPress and Woocommerce is running already in its latest version. I had read some articles that it might because of some logs are not yet removed which triggers something like that. Is it possible?

Comment: alright. I'll try to locate what you suggested. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the page of source code https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#636-645, you can see

```
   /**
     * Gets the url to the cart page.
     *
     * @deprecated 2.5.0 in favor to wc_get_cart_url()
     *
     * @return string url to page
     */
    public function get_cart_url() {
        return wc_get_cart_url();
    }
```

Use the wc_get_cart_url().